# Unable to figure out the error in my code

Tags: c++, stack

I was trying out the [Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation](https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/description/) problem. I seem to run into a runtime error:

```
Line 171: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:180:16
```

The code is shared below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) {
        int n {static_cast<int>(tokens.size())}, x {0}, y{0};
        stack<int> st;
        for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
            if ( (tokens[i][0] >= '0')&&(tokens[i][0] <= '9') ){
                st.push(tokens[i][0] - '0');
            }else{
                y = st.top();
                st.pop();
                x = st.top();
                st.pop();
                switch(tokens[i][0]){
                    case '+':
                        st.push(x+y);
                        break;
                    case '-':
                        st.push(x-y);
                        break;
                    case '*':
                        st.push(x*y);
                        break;
                    case '/':
                        st.push(x/y);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return st.top();
    }
};
```

I am possibly accessing some 'misaligned address' ? What exactly does this error message mean, and what have I done wrong ? Interestingly though, I am able to run it without any issues in an online c++ compiler: [Same code on online C++ compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/AXAQPkN5g).

What is missing?

I have tried running the code on other online compilers and it seems to have worked without any hassle.

Comment: You never check if the stack is empty before assuming it isn't. What is some sample input that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: What is the test data that fails?  Also, please post the code here, as what you posted is not a [mcve].

Comment: `y = st.top(); st.pop(); x = st.top();` -- What happens if `st.pop()` causes the stack to be empty?  You are then calling `st.top()`, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Given the problem, the stack won't be empty. The bigger issue is assuming that you're only ever pushing single digits. `"13" - '0'` isn't what you think it would be. On my machine, it's `2099808` (for that particular run) if I represent it as a `int64_t`. You're doing pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the question mentioned that it will be a valid 'reverse polish sequence' so this would mean that checking for emptiness is not required for stack. Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: @sweenish understood. This is an error on my part, I actually wanted to do this without using any inbuild functions. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it fails to compile on leetcode platform but seems to run on online compiler platforms. I am not sure how to produce a more minimal example untill I know *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: @prasun Leetcode gives you the test case(s) that fail.  I went directly to that site, and entered your code.  The test case that Leetcode gives that fails is `"10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+"`.   Also, [here is your code, written using correct C++, that demonstrates the issue](https://godbolt.org/z/nx1c6fsYK).

Comment: *I actually wanted to do this without using any inbuild functions.* -- You are using `std::vector`, `std::stack`, etc.  What is an "inbuild function"?  Second, thing is that the code I gave in the previous comment is exactly how you should test your code on a local compiler.  That is to create a `main` program, and inside `main` instantiate a `Solution` object, and call the function of `Solution` with the failing testcase data.  Then you have a chance to actually debug the code locally.

Comment: @prasun The question says no such thing. The external link might but I don't visit those and I shouldn't have to. All information necessary to answer the question should be here not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, the issue is the assumption that you're only ever passing single digit numbers. The `- '0'` conversion only works on a character. But the sample inputs clearly show non-single-digit numbers. Something like `"13" - '0'` is actually doing pointer arithmetic, meaning your result is a memory address, and things go sideways from there.

Here's a tweaked solution that uses [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

The second expression in my `if` case that checks if I have a number is necessary to handle negative numbers. I also opted for [`std::isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) over the character range checking because it's easier to write.

This solution had a runtime of 3ms (beats 98.77%) and memory usage of 11.91MB (beats 51.96%).

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int evalRPN(std::vector<std::string> const & tokens) {
      std::stack<int> s;
      for (auto const & token : tokens) {
        if (std::isdigit(token[0]) || (token.size() > 1 && std::isdigit(token[1]))) {
          s.push(std::stoi(token));
        } else {
          int rhs = s.top();
          s.pop();
          int lhs = s.top();
          s.pop();

          if (token == "+") {
            s.push(lhs + rhs);
          } else if (token == "-") {
            s.push(lhs - rhs);
          } else if (token == "*") {
            s.push(lhs * rhs);
          } else {
            s.push(lhs / rhs);
          }
        }
      }

      return s.top();
    }
};
```

Some well-placed `cout`s can help you see the calculation run step-by-step.

```cpp
          std::cout << lhs << " " << token << " " << rhs;
          if (token == "+") {
            s.push(lhs + rhs);
          } else if (token == "-") {
            s.push(lhs - rhs);
          } else if (token == "*") {
            s.push(lhs * rhs);
          } else {
            s.push(lhs / rhs);
          }
          std::cout << " = " << s.top() << '\n';
```

If we take the sample inputs and throw them into a sample program:

```cpp
int main() {
  Solution s;
  std::cout << s.evalRPN({"2", "1", "+", "3", "*"}) << '\n';
  std::cout << s.evalRPN({"4", "13", "5", "/", "+"}) << '\n';
  std::cout << s.evalRPN({"10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+"}) << '\n';
}
```

Our output will be:

```
2 + 1 = 3
3 * 3 = 9
9
13 / 5 = 2
4 + 2 = 6
6
9 + 3 = 12
12 * -11 = -132
6 / -132 = 0
10 * 0 = 0
0 + 17 = 17
17 + 5 = 22
22
```

Here's one solution using a mapping. Somewhat surprisingly, it is (so far) at best equivalent to my first run, or my first run got lucky as far as run times go. This solution ranges from 3 - 13ms, and even the memory used fluctuates. Submitting the same code multiple times, the best run had a runtime of 3ms (beats 98.77%) and memory usage of 11.84MB (beats 89.36%).

I am unsure that my marking the branch that pushes a number to the stack as [`[[likely]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/likely) helped get lower run times. There will be a 2:1 ratio of numbers to operators.

It's likely to do with heap access and cache misses due to map elements not being in contiguous memory.

```cpp
class Solution {
 public:
  int evalRPN(std::vector<std::string> const& tokens) {
    static const std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void(int&, int)>>
        funcMap{{"+", [](int& stackTop, int b) { stackTop += b; }},
                {"-", [](int& stackTop, int b) { stackTop -= b; }},
                {"*", [](int& stackTop, int b) { stackTop *= b; }},
                {"/", [](int& stackTop, int b) { stackTop /= b; }}};

    std::stack<int> s;
    for (auto const& token : tokens) {
      auto const& op = funcMap.find(token);
      if (op == funcMap.end()) [[likely]] {
        s.push(std::stoi(token));
      } else {
        int rhs = s.top();
        s.pop();
        op->second(s.top(), rhs);
      }
    }

    return s.top();
  }
};
```

The code is at least more compact, and maybe a bit more efficient for very large `tokens`. Ease of maintenance is a wash to me. Let's not forget that we're only talking a worst-case difference of 10ms. There are situations where that's a big deal, but this really isn't one of them. Especially with how inconsistent the leetcode runs can be.

If you wanted to pop both operands, that would allow you use `std::plus<int>()`, et al. instead of user-defined lambdas.

Comment: Okay, I finally understand the reason behind the error thanks to your explanation. Cannot give you an upvote due to my low reputation, but I will get there someday. Can you please share the syntax for storing a map of the operations which you referred to in the end of your answer.

Comment: @prasun I added another solution that uses function mapping. It's actually not faster. I briefly discuss why that could be in the answer.

Comment: There are lots of interesting ways to tackle this problem. I just read one that doesn't bother with a stack. It has great memory usage. It all depends on what your desires/constraints are.

Answer (score 1):

###### A short answer to the question...

> What is missing?

As was explained in the comments above, and also in the solution by @sweenish, the code posted in your question incorrectly assumes that operands contain only a single digit. Furthermore, your conversion from `std::string` to `int` was problematic.

###### Followed by a rather lengthy explanation of a possible solution

Rather than repeat what others have said, I would like to discuss my approach to this coding challenge, starting with a general observation.

###### **LeetCode** challenges are rife with issues.

Near the top of the list is that LeetCode teaches a style of coding that does not involve trapping bad inputs. Any good first course in programming teaches that a program must be robust when faced with invalid input, but LeetCode pretends that is not important.

Instead, LeetCode teaches programmers to scrap for every byte of storage and nanosecond of execution time, while ignoring issues of program readability and maintainability. Top programmers know that efficiency counts in the critical parts of a program. Everywhere else, readability and maintainability generally top efficiency.

That does not mean you should write sloppy code; just the opposite. It means you should write clean, easy-to-understand code, and let the compiler worry about optimizing for efficiency in all but the most critical sections.

The programmer optimizes by selecting the right data structures and alogrithms, not by nitpicking every line of their implementations.

Another problem with LeetCode is that its `Solutions` do not const-qualify their arguments. On top of that, LeetCode does not state in its problem specs whether the arguments to a `Solution` may be modified, or whether your code should treat them as constant.

This causes two issues:

1. Any constant object that is passed to a `Solution` must be copied to a non-constant object first.
2. If the plan is to avoid modifying one of the arguments to a `Solution` function, then, for clarity, you may want to copy it to a constant object inside the `Solution`. This is fine, but if you need the "local" copy to be an instance variable, then the copy cannot be declared `const`!

This second point makes it clear that LeetCode should use a constructor for many of its challenges, so that instance members can be properly initialized. More broadly, it makes the point that *LeetCode does not teach proper class design.*

A final pet-peeve is that, in my opinion, the LeetCode `Solution` functions should be static member functions, rather than instance members. After you solve a few of the challenges, you may find that you agree.

###### A solution with error-checking

In the case of this RPN evaluator, adding error checking is relatively easy. It falls out of the algorithm.

In my implementation, I chose to use `std::vector` rather than `std::stack`. Variable `stack_` is an instance member, so every time I enter member function `RPNeval`, I need to call `stack_.clear()` to make sure there is no garbage remaining from prior invocations. Unfortunately, `std::stack` does not have member `clear`, so I went with `std::vector`.

More importantly, my toolbox has a couple of handy functions that can be used to convert vector objects into strings, which makes them easy to display and include in error messages.

- `tbx::cast_to_string( std::vector<int> const& )`
- `tbx::cast_to_string( std::vector<std::string> const& )`

Since I did not want to recode them to work with `std::stack`, I had a strong incentive to stick with `std::vector`.

Another nice function in my toolbox is `tbx::cast_to<int>`. I prefer it over `std::stoi`, because it requires that the conversion completely consume the input string, and also because it has built-in checks for range. In this case, operands are checked according the spec provided by LeetCode: they must be (inclusively) between `-200` and `+200`.
`tbx::cast_to<int>` returns true when it succeeds; false, otherwise.

In the example below, variable `t` is a string token that needs to be converted to an `int`.
Variable `operand` is an output parameter, i.e., a reference parameter. When `tbx::cast_to<int>` succeeds, `operand` returns the result. When `tbx::cast_to<int>` fails, `operand` returns the value `0`.

```cpp
if (int operand; tbx::cast_to<int>(operand, -200, 200, t))
    stack_.push_back(operand);
else
    throw std::runtime_error(invalid_token(t));
```

These three functions from my toolbox are not difficult to write. In the interest of brevity, they are not included in the source code below. If you would like to see them, let me know by putting a request in the comments.

I begin every LeetCode problem the same way: I code a short stub designed to reproduce the examples shown on the LeetCode website. Even at this stage, I often use function `tbx::cast_to_string` from my toolbox.

Here is the output produced by the stub. You get the answer `0` every time:

```
LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation
https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/

Example 1

  Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3","*"]
  Output: 0

Example 2

  Input: tokens = ["4","13","5","/","+"]
  Output: 0

Example 3

  Input: tokens = ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+"]
  Output: 0
```

And, here are the two modules that produced it:

```cpp
// main.ixx
export module main;
import LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation;
export int main()
{
    return LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation() ? 0 : 1;
}
```

```cpp
// LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation.ixx
export module LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation;
import std;
import tbx.utility;  // "toolbox" functions

// These using declarations allow the LeetCode Solution 
// to be used without modifying its function signature.
using std::string;
using std::vector;

class Solution {
public:
    int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) {
        return {};
    }
};
void solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::vector<std::string> const& tokens)
{
    auto t{ tokens };
    std::cout << std::format(
        "{}"
        "\n"
        "\n  Input: tokens = {}"
        "\n  Output: {}"
        "\n\n"
        , heading
        , tbx::cast_to_string(tokens)
        , Solution{}.evalRPN(t)
    );
}
export bool LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation() {
    std::cout << "LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/"
        "\n\n";
    solve("Example 1", { "2", "1", "+", "3", "*" });
    solve("Example 2", { "4", "13", "5", "/", "+" });
    solve("Example 3", { "10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+" });
    return true;
}
// end file: LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation.ixx
```

Later on, after I had inserted error handling into class `Solution`, I modified function `solve`, so that it could catch any exceptions that were thrown by function `evalRPN`:

```cpp
bool solve(
    std::string_view heading,
    std::vector<std::string> const& tokens)
{
    auto t{ tokens };
    std::string eval_string;
    bool good{ true };
    try {
        auto eval{ Solution{}.evalRPN(t) };
        eval_string = std::to_string(eval);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& e) {
        good = false;
        eval_string = e.what();
    }

    std::cout << std::format(
        "{}"
        "\n"
        "\n  Input: tokens = {}"
        "\n  Output: {}"
        "\n\n"
        , heading
        , tbx::cast_to_string(tokens)
        , eval_string
    );
    return good;
}
```

I also added a few error cases to function `LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation`, along with variable `good`, which flags errors. If any of the calls to function `solve` return `false`, variable `good` will be assigned `false`, and thereafter remain `false`.

```cpp
export bool LeetCode_0150_Evaluate_Reverse_Polish_Notation() {
    std::cout << "LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation"
        "\nhttps://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/"
        "\n\n";
    bool good{ true };
    good = solve("Example 1", { "2", "1", "+", "3", "*" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 2", { "4", "13", "5", "/", "+" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 3", { "10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "17", "+", "5", "+" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 4: Single value", { "42" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 5: Single operator", { "/" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 6: Empty expression", {}) && good;
    good = solve("Example 7: Malformed expression", { "2", "1", "+", "3" }) && good;
    good = solve("Example 8: Malformed expression", { "10", "6", "9", "3", "+", "-11", "*", "/", "*", "+", "17", "+", "5", "+"}) && good;
    return good;
}
```

Even with the stub `Solution`, everything still works fine. Of course, the output is always `0`, as you expect for the stub, but otherwise, the error cases are now included in the output:

```
LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation
https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/

Example 1

  Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3","*"]
  Output: 0

Example 2

  Input: tokens = ["4","13","5","/","+"]
  Output: 0

Example 3

  Input: tokens = ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+"]
  Output: 0

Example 4: Single value

  Input: tokens = ["42"]
  Output: 0

Example 5: Single operator

  Input: tokens = ["/"]
  Output: 0

Example 6: Empty expression

  Input: tokens = []
  Output: 0

Example 7: Malformed expression

  Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3"]
  Output: 0

Example 8: Malformed expression

  Input: tokens = ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","+","17","+","5","+"]
  Output: 0
```

With this framework, writing class `Solution` was relatively straightforward. For clarity, I used functions `add`, `subtract`, `multiply` and `divide`. I expect the compiler to inline them. As stated above, I am coding for readability.

In the solution below, I wanted the vector of `tokens` to be an instance member. That is why I copy it to variable `tokens_` at the begining of function `evalRPN`. I could avoid this copy by passing a reference to `tokens` to each of the functions in class `Solution`. For example, I could pass it down through `add` and `check_stack_size`, to arrive, finally, in function `state`, where it is used as part of an error message. Although that might be more efficient, I chose to avoid the clutter, along with the overhead of passing the references around.

```cpp
class Solution {
    std::vector<int> stack_;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens_;
public:
    int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) {
        tokens_ = tokens;
        stack_.clear();
        for (auto const& t : tokens_) {
            if (t == "+")
                add();
            else if (t == "-")
                subtract();
            else if (t == "*")
                multiply();
            else if (t == "/")
                divide();
            else if (int operand; tbx::cast_to<int>(operand, -200, 200, t))
                stack_.push_back(operand);
            else
                throw std::runtime_error(invalid_token(t));
        }
        if (stack_.size() != 1)
            throw std::runtime_error(invalid_expression());
        return stack_.back();
    }
private:
    void add()
    {
        check_stack_size('+');
        auto const operand{ stack_.back() };
        stack_.pop_back();
        stack_.back() += operand;
    }
    void subtract()
    {
        check_stack_size('-');
        auto const operand{ stack_.back() };
        stack_.pop_back();
        stack_.back() -= operand;
    }
    void multiply()
    {
        check_stack_size('*');
        auto const operand{ stack_.back() };
        stack_.pop_back();
        stack_.back() *= operand;
    }
    void divide()
    {
        check_stack_size('/');
        auto const operand{ stack_.back() };
        stack_.pop_back();
        stack_.back() /= operand;
    }
    auto state()
    {
        return std::format(
            "    tokens : {}\n"
            "    stack_ : {}\n"
            , tbx::cast_to_string(tokens_)
            , tbx::cast_to_string(stack_)
        );
    }
    void check_stack_size(char const op)
    {
        if (stack_.size() < 2)
            throw std::runtime_error(
                std::format(
                    "ERROR Solution{{}}.evalRPN(tokens) - "
                    "operator '{}' requires two operands.\n"
                    , op) + state()
            );
    }
    auto invalid_expression()
    {
        return "ERROR Solution{}.evalRPN(tokens): "
            "tokens does not contain a valid expression.\n"
            + state();
    }
    auto invalid_token(std::string const& t)
    {
        return std::format(
            "Solution{{}}.evalRPN(tokens) - "
            "invalid token: \"{}\"\n"
            , t) + state();
    }
};
```

Now the output replicates nicely the examples from the LeetCode website, and also includes error messages for the examples that fail:

```
LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation
https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-reverse-polish-notation/

Example 1

  Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3","*"]
  Output: 9

Example 2

  Input: tokens = ["4","13","5","/","+"]
  Output: 6

Example 3

  Input: tokens = ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","17","+","5","+"]
  Output: 22

Example 4: Single value

  Input: tokens = ["42"]
  Output: 42

Example 5: Single operator

  Input: tokens = ["/"]
  Output: ERROR Solution{}.evalRPN(tokens) - operator '/' requires two operands.
    tokens : ["/"]
    stack_ : []


Example 6: Empty expression

  Input: tokens = []
  Output: ERROR Solution{}.evalRPN(tokens): tokens does not contain a valid expression.
    tokens : []
    stack_ : []


Example 7: Malformed expression

  Input: tokens = ["2","1","+","3"]
  Output: ERROR Solution{}.evalRPN(tokens): tokens does not contain a valid expression.
    tokens : ["2","1","+","3"]
    stack_ : [3,3]


Example 8: Malformed expression

  Input: tokens = ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","+","17","+","5","+"]
  Output: ERROR Solution{}.evalRPN(tokens) - operator '+' requires two operands.
    tokens : ["10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*","+","17","+","5","+"]
    stack_ : [0]
```

Comment: "Another problem with LeetCode is that its Solutions do not const-qualify their arguments. On top of that, LeetCode does not state in its problem specs whether the arguments to a Solution can be modified." Both are non-issues. This particular problem has stack-less solutions that require the argument be modifiable. As to whether you can or not, at some point the user will just try. I have my issues with leetcode, but an answer to this question is not the place for them to be aired, except for maybe a (much shorter) comment.

Comment: LeetCode, StackOverflow, and beginners are a bad mix. This question is a good example. Once again, the poor newbie who asked for help, got slammed by a series of down votes. That's not a nice welcome to StackOverflow. I took the time to explain a few of the reasons why LeetCode is viewed negatively, so that the OP would perhaps learn something about LeetCode that he had not considered. Regarding "whether you can or not", I misspoke. I meant "may": The specs never say whether you _may_ modify the arguments. I have updated that line in my post.

Comment: I don't disagree with your general sentiment. I do disagree with a lot of your specifics. Like your first paragraph going after leetcode. If you're just looking to implement an algorithm, sanitizing inputs just creates noise. Yes, it's good practice to do so, but it ends up getting in the way of learning the algorithm/data structure. Do that, then circle back tighten it up. It's just that an answer to this question is not the place to air those grievances. Maybe a better tack would be describing the benefits of TDD. FWIW, the downvote isn't mine.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation, @tbxfreeware . It will be a while before I am able to internalize your comments. I am a beginner at 23 learning to code, and stack overflow seems to be the only place where there are people who are kind enough to help out a newbie.